# I need these images to display next to each other

Tags: html, css

This seems like it should be so simple but playing around for hours I cannot figure out how to make the linkedIn and GitHub images show up next to each other.

```
 <h1>Contact Me:</h1>

<p>
    <div>
            <h2>School Email:</h2>
    <a class="tabbed" href="mailto:me@email.com">me@email.com</a> 
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div>
            <h2>Check me out on:</h2>   <span class="images">
                                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/john-doe" target="_blank"><img style="border:none; margin-top: 5px;" src="http://s8.postimg.org/6x5pyi5o1/Linkedinbutton.gif" alt="LinkedIn"></a><br><br>
                                        <a href="https://github.com/johndoe" target="_blank"><img title="Check me out on GitHub!" style="border:none; margin-top: 5px;" src="http://s22.postimg.org/ujhomd9st/Git_Hub.png" alt="GitHub"></a><br><br>
                                    </span>

    </div>
    <div>
            <h2>School Address:</h2>

        <p class="tabbed">Sandburg Residence Hall Box #S1993
            <br>3400 N Maryland Avenue
            <br>Milwaukee Wi, 53211
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
</p>
<p style="font-size:13px;">This page was created with the help and much thanks of <a href="http://code.google.com/p/how-to-create-tabs-in-html-using-jquery/downloads/detail?name=how-to-create-tabs-in-html-using-jquery.zip&can=2&q=s">this</a> tutorial.</p>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKXSD/12/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
.images img {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and delete both breaks `<br>`... **or** just delete both of the breaks.

[<kbd>Demo here</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/WkrcC/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the two < br >'s

```
<span class="images">
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/john-doe" target="_blank"><img style="border:none; margin-top: 5px;float:left;" src="http://s8.postimg.org/6x5pyi5o1/Linkedinbutton.gif" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/johndoe" target="_blank"><img title="Check me out on GitHub!" style="border:none; margin-top: 5px;" src="http://s22.postimg.org/ujhomd9st/Git_Hub.png" alt="GitHub"></a><br><br>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKXSD/15/

Comment: Yeah ... I'm stupid. Didn't see those probably should have made my screen wider =P

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `<br><br>` between them and its all done. No need to anything.

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/JaLb7/)

Answer (score 2):

The two `<BR>`'s won't help ;)

and no float left is needed....

if you still encounter problems, just add `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, and I have to emphasize that it really matters what you need images for, but it would be better to just have a plain text link and use your image as a background image of it. Sure, it is a bit fiddly, but it will save you loads of positioning issues.

Check out this link:
http://ran.ge/2009/11/11/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/